# how do I make a form control and its label be inline and centered than as the screen shrinks have them on top of each other but still centered?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to make a form control and it's label centered and inline together then make them stack on top of each other (label over input textbox) as the screen shrinks? I'm trying to do this with bootstrap.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. In order for people to help you better you should provide the code that you have already tried and explain what is not working. [You can read more here on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS breakpoints to define different styles depending on screensize. Since you are using bootstrap, you can utilize their grid system.

Look at advanced form layouts -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row